# Forcing CodeIgniter to send view and stop working

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor, preventdefault

Hello I'm using inherited controllers. These are my controllers:

-baseAdminController:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
class _BaseAdminController extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');

        $calledFunction= $this->router->fetch_method();
        if ($calledFunction!= 'loginView' && $calledFunction!= 'doLogin') {
            $this->checkSession();
        }
    }

    public function checkSession() {

        if ($this->session->userdata('loggedIn') == false) {
            $this->load->view('admin/loginView');
        }
    }
}
```

And my derived Admin Controllers:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class AdminController extends _BaseAdminController {

    public function indexView() {
        $this->load->view('admin/indexView');
    }
}
```

When i'm tring to login, CodeIgniter shows me both admin/loginView and admin/indexView. Because i'm checking session status at constructing my derived controller. How can i prevent to loading second view?

Thank in advance..

Comment: You probably want to redirect the user to the login page, instead of loading a view.

Comment: Use `exit();` or `die();` after loading `admin/loginView` view, give it a try, I didn't.

Comment: @HashemQolami Yes i tried them both and won't work..

Comment: @Jeemusu Thank you. I was completely forgot about redirect()..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, you could have done the following into your **checkSession** method:

```
public function checkSession() {

    if ($this->session->userdata('loggedIn') == false) {
        echo $this->load->view('admin/loginView', array(), TRUE);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Explanation: If you pass the third argument as TRUE, it will return the content of that file. Read [ellislab.com](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is related to your question:

I recently wanted to have a bunch of controllers extend a parent controller class (MY_Acl_Controller) that checked that the current logged-in user deserved access to each method (using a homegrown ACL library). The check was to be initiated in MY_Acl_Controller's constructor, so it would run on every request.

I wanted to set the Output class's output to the result of loading a view, then display the view and exit, but because this process was NOT executed in a routed controller method, I couldn't just call $this->load->view('errors/access_denied') and then return from the constructor function... CI would then carry on executing controller code.

So I created a MY_Output class, extending CI_Output, and added to it a public function display_with_exit():

```
public function display_with_exit()
{
    $this->_display($this->final_output);
    exit;
}
```

Then, in MY_Acl_Controller's constructor:

```
...
if(!$user_deserves_access)
{
    $this->load->view('errors/access_denied');
    $this->output->display_with_exit();
}
```

Maybe that might be useful to someone?

The advantage of this approach is that the Output class's _display() function sends all HTTP headers you'd like it to, as per any normal response.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `exit;` / `function exit;` or `die;` will terminate execution, its better practice in only debugging your code.

Try like below.

```
public function index(){
  if($xx) return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Could you re-format your answer and expand the example? It's a little difficult to understand as-is.